# rs.getString() only selected columns for dynamic select statement

Tags: java, jdbc

I've a dynamic query, which is like:-

```
"SELECT " + commaSeparatedFields + " FROM table"
```

Now, while getting the result set, I want to check if a field is selected, if true, set the value in a bean, else set null.

Sample code explaining what I want to do:-

```
Bean bean = new Bean(
    isSelected(rs, "FIRSTNAME") ? rs.getString("FIRSTNAME") : null, 
    isSelected(rs, "LASTNAME") ? rs.getString("LASTNAME") : null, 
    isSelected(rs, "EMAIL") ? rs.getString("EMAIL") : null);
```

what should be the content of `isSelected` method? and How good would be the performance of this approach?

Comment: Please check on ResultSetMetadata which has column names

Comment: I think answers by @AStranger, Michael Sanchez and Daniel would work perfect. I was actually implementing what Daniel has done. But which of these would have the best peformance?

Comment: I think Michael Sanchez is gives a good solution (Simple and Faster). But please take care that `contains` is a case sensitive method and SQL is case-insensitive

Comment: Have you considered whether this code is really a good choice design-wise? It certainly is a wet glove in the face of static typing.

Comment: @Kaushik Well without context it's hard to know what's really going on, but that looks quit awkward. Since you know the field, you can get rid of the constructor initialization and use setters instead. It seems that Michael Sanchez already suggested this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you know the values passed in `commaSeparatedFields`? If you do, just make a `.contains` call instead of the isSelected approach. I hope I understood your need.

Comment: I think `.contains` check can be done in isSelected method if needed :)

Answer (score 2):

Did you try ResultsetMetadata. Sample is given below

```
public boolean isSelected(ResultSet rs, String columnName) throws SQLException
{

    ResultSetMetaData meta=rs.getMetaData();

    for(int i=0;i<meta.getColumnCount();i++)
    {
        if(meta.getColumnName(i).equals(columnName))
            return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

Comment: This piece of code gives good performance rather @krishna code, there we need to create List evertime we iterate..

Answer (score 1):

In case your query will handle only strings, you can change to a function which extracts the value:

```
String getColumnValue(ResultSet rs , String columnName){
    try{
        return rs.getString(columnName);
    }catch(SqlException){

        return null;
    }
}
```

or use the class `ResultSetMetaData`, which is quite flexible for dynamic queries, like yours.

```
ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
ResultSetMetaData rsmd = rs.getMetaData();

for (int i = 1; i <= rsmd.getColumnCount(); i++) {
    //do your job here
    //rsmd.getColumnType(i))
    //rsmd.getColumnLabel(i)
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Possible pseudo code can be - (You can add few more checks as per your requirement)

```
public boolean isSelected(ResultSet rs, String column){
    return (rs.getString(column) != null);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simplest is to use contains as @Michael suggested on the columnnames string directly or by splitting it by "," and checking.

Alternatively, using metadata. I haven't tried it, but, this might be helpful.

```
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT a, b, c FROM TABLE2");
     ResultSetMetaData rsmd = rs.getMetaData();
     int numberOfColumns = rsmd.getColumnCount();
    ArrayList<String> selectedColumns= new ArrayList();
     for (int i=0; i<numberOfColumns ;i++) {
    selectedColumns.add(rsmd.getColumnName(i));
     }

     if (selectedColumns.contains(columnName) {
//TODO: Do something
}
```

Comment: there will be two loopings occured. one for create the columns list and second for contains() method

Comment: That is right. Just wanted to indicate how resultset metadata could be used. As I mentioned, best approach is what Michael suggested - using contains and setters.